# How to set background of tablerow items to encompass entire cell?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a table full of textViews that looks like this:
[image]

The textviews have their background property set, but how can I make it take up the whitespace above and below so they line up with the height of the tablerow rather than the textview?

Comment: Did you try to set the TextView height to match_parent rather than wrap_content?

Comment: Tried that - It causes a null pointer exception...